# php if else with function shorthand

Tags: php, conditional-operator, shorthand

How can i write this shortly?

```
$abc = file_get_contents('one.txt');
if($abc !== '')
{
msg($abc);
} else {
msg('nope');
}
```

I tried:

```
$abc = file_get_contents('one.txt');
if($abc !== '') ? msg($abc) : msg('nope');
```

or

```
$abc = file_get_contents('one.txt');
msg if($abc !== '') ? $abc : 'nope';
```

and not working, please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use the `if` keyword when writing a ternary expression.

```
($abc != '') ? msg($abc) : msg('nope');
```

or

```
msg($abc != '' ? $abc : 'nope');
```

Comment: `msg($abc ? $abc : 'Nope')`?

Comment: `msg($abc ?: 'Nope');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
msg(($abc = file_get_contents('blah.txt')) ? $abc : 'Nope');
```

I don't like to suppress errors but maybe:

```
msg(($abc = @file_get_contents('blah.txt')) ? $abc : 'Nope');
```